# regexp_replace is replacing my string with multiple periods in between capture groups when I only want one period

Tags: regex, regex-group, regexp-replace, regex-greedy

Hi I am using regexp_replace in an SQL query that uses AWS Athena in order to change a version number in a user agent from 16_0 to 16.0

Instead of getting `16.0` back, I am getting `16.0..` back? If I remove the `.` between `$1` and `$2` I get `160` so this makes me believe my regex is correct but for some reason my replacement string is adding two periods at the end when I only want a single period in the middle.

This is an example of one of the user agents (note I am also parsing iPads too)

`Mozilla/5.0%20(iPhone;%20CPU%20iPhone%20OS%2016_1%20like%20Mac%20OS%20X)%20AppleWebKit/605.1.15%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20CriOS/108.0.5359.52%20Mobile/15E148%20Safari/604.1`

This is my regex replace statement:

```
    regexp_replace(
        useragent,
        '.*?(?<=OS%20)(\d+)_(\d{1,2})|.*',
        '$1.$2'
      )
```

Edited to add: I have tried a variety of regex combinations, such as greedy or no lookbehinds, etc and test on regex101 but to no avail.

AHA! - I believe it is adding two periods because it is getting 2 more matches with a null for capture groups and adding the period per each. I need to figure out how to stop it. Relatively new to regex

Comment: You have `|.*`. That will give an extra match, which will be replaced by a dot (since `$1` and `$2` will be empty).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just match everything and capture only what you want, if your goal is to replace everything anyway? Something like `.*?OS%20(\d+)_(\d{1,2}).*` and replace with your substitute. Edit: to add to what Poul Bak said, `.*` will be used to match both the rest of your string and the empty position after it (since nothing is a valid match for `*`), so you get two more matches.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out matching everything after! I still need the `|.*` after for my use-case to have null when no matches. I was able to replace this with `|.+` as suggested by the accepted answer. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact you are not matching the rest of the string after the version in the first alternative, and the second `.*` alternative matches the rest of the string, and then the end of string position.

You can use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/xt8N0L/1)

```
.*?OS%20(\d+)_(\d{1,2}).*
```

to capture the version parts and consume the whole string. Note that this pattern has no alternative to match the whole string if there is no version in the string because in that case you will get a `.` in the output (`$1` and `$2` will be empty if the version is missing). If you still need that behavior, replace `.*` with `.+` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xt8N0L/2)):

```
.*?OS%20(\d+)_(\d{1,2}).*|.+
```

to match at least one char other than line break chars, as many as possible.

Comment: Amazing - Thanks! I used the second solution and it worked perfectly! Both did work but I opted for the second approach because I do need the behavior matching null when no matches for my use-case. Thanks so much for the explanation